# Installing snort, having trouble with SQL root password

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, snort

So I am installing snort currently on my ubuntu linux server. I am following [this guide here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/snort-org-site/production/document_files/files/000/000/065/original/Snort_2.9.7.x_on_Ubuntu_12_and_14.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIXACIED2SPMSC7GA&Expires=1447199387&Signature=4OK8Cs%2Bdigm%2FxLAq601V3Fryp8k%3D).

At this point, I am at the part in the guide where I am installing Barnyard2 and i need to access my SQL database to save information. linux server is near fresh install with little else on it. When I try to do this part of the guide:

```
echo "create database snort;" | mysql -u root -p
mysql -u root -p -D snort < ~/snort_src/barnyard2-master/schemas/create_mysql
echo "grant create, insert, select, delete, update on snort.* to \
snort@localhost identified by 'MYSQLSNORTPASSWORD'" | mysql -u root -p
```

When I run the first line - if I don't enter anything, I get the error message that says:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

If I do enter something, I get a different error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I have tried using [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MysqlPasswordReset) in order to reset my password but the command `mysql -u root` or any form of command similiar results back in the same error, even when it says the password is probably not required for this command. Does anyone know a way in which I can get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you break that down into chunks?

First make the database:

```
$ mysql -u root -p -e 'CREATE DATABASE `snort`'
```

Import the barnyard schema

```
$ mysql -u root -p < ~/snort_src/barnyard2-master/schemas/create_mysql
```

Now create the user & assign permissions for the snort db to the barnyard user

```
$ mysql -u root -p -e 'GRANT CREATE, INSERT, SELECT, DELETE, UPDATE ON `snort`.* TO snort@localhost IDENTIFIED BY '[SNORT PASSSWORD]'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
i cant make the database in the first line because of the error im getting unfortunetly

Answer (score 0):

The commands in your question are running a local `mysql` client which assumes to connect to a local database by default. If your database is running on a neighbouring Windows box you will need to [rethink your parameters](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/connecting.html).

`mysql -u root -p -h 192.168.0.99`